# Is it possible to have tsc typecheck a source file but not emit javascript

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc

I have a situation where there are some `.ts` files that exist only for type-testing. Is it possible to tell tsc to not emit js in `outDir` for some files. But still typecheck them. And possibly these test files don't need to be under `rootDir`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set [noEmit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmit) to true:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

or use the `--noEmit` flag when running `tsc` to stop it outputting files.

Comment: This option will stop emission of _all_ source files. I've come to the conclusion that this is not possible.